# Проблемы с буквами Е Ё

Tags: php, sql, plpgsql

В БД имеются дублирующие друг друга записи у которых отличаются только буквы **Е** и **Ё**. Например, есть две записи актер и актёр. Постгресс считает, что это разные слова, соответственно выводит только одно из них по точному совпадению. Можно ли как-то средствами пхп приравнять эти буквы друг к другу и выводить оба слова независимо от того какая буква была написана?

Comment: а в запросе к базе незя 2 условие?

Comment: Не понял что вы хотите сказать.

Comment: @Bloom не самая хорошая идея, с увеличением числа букв е/ё в условии получается комбинаторный взрыв

Comment: откажитесь от использования буквы `ё`в БД и проблемы не будет :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте unaccent вашей базы данных, который позволяет строить связи между разными литерами, обозначающими одну и ту же сущность.

```
À        A
Á        A
Â        A
Ã        A
Ä        A
Å        A
Æ        A
```

Документация: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/unaccent.html

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете изменить свой SELECT запрос, заменив перед поиском Ё на Е используюя функцию [REPLACE](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_replace_function.html)

И перед отправкой запроса средствами php заменить все Ё на Е в строке которую отправите.

```
 $str = str_replace('ё', 'е', $str);
```

Таким образом, строка по которой будет осуществен поиск не будет содержать букву Ё и строки по которым будем искать, тоже не будут содержать Ё. При этом запрос вернет строки с правильными буквами (как они записаны в БД)

Comment: В таком случае, в поиск не будут попадать слова с Ё.

Comment: Ошибка, сейчас поправлю текст. Нужно использовать и REPLACE и str_replace

Comment: А вообще можно обойтись только функцие REPLACE. Просто в запросе заменять строку по которой ищем и строку в которой ищем